# How to set fonticon in textviews in android

Tags: android

I have unicode for Ex: f217, I have already done:

```
Typeface fonticon = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
textview.setTypeface(fonticon)
```

but when I set the text in textview it takes it like:
`textview.setText("\uf217");`
I am able to do it when I directly use this fonticon, but not able to set it when I have this fonticon in a string. I am getting this unicode from server, so I cannot create a string also in strings.xml file.

Please suggest me how can I achieve this.

Comment: What Charset are you using? String by default use UTF - 8

Comment: I am also using same.

Comment: try this code
Typeface fonticon = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/"fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
      textview.setTypeface(fonticon);
   http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_custom_fonts.htm

Comment: pl explain what you exactly mean "I am able to do it when I directly use this fonticon, but not able to set it when I have this fonticon in a string"

Comment: Actually I have this fonticon in a string Ex: String icon = "f127" and I am getting this icon from server just the code only f127. 
Now I want to set it to textview, so I need a string like "\uf127" but when I try to add "\u" in this string of icon, it gives me error.
How can I do it, please suggest me.